# C# : game sound when user presses a key quickly

Tags: c#, audio

I'm trying to create a flappy bird clone and I'm a little stuck on the game effects.
I'm using the SoundPlayer class to load a .wav file and play it when the user presses a key to make the bird go higher.

But my problem is when the user keeps pressing the key or presses the same key quickly again.

The sound is cut-off each time you replay the sound (if it isn't finished yet).

How can I solve this? Is there a way to check if the sound has finished before replaying it again?

Or maybe using the SoundPlayer class isn't the right one to use for this purpose?

First load the .wav file :

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer flyUp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"flyUp.wav");
```

And then in the KeyDown event, play it :

```
private void frmMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (gameState)
            {
                case GameState.game:
                    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
                    {
                        flyUp.Play();
                        iGravity = -3;
                    }
                    
                    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
                    {
                        this.Close();
                    }
                    break;

                case GameState.gameover:
                    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        gameState = GameState.reload;
                    }

                    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
                    {
                        this.Close();
                    }
                    break;

                case GameState.reload:
                    Reload();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making this handler async?
like that-

```
private async void frmMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (gameState)
        {
            case GameState.game:
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
                {
                    flyUp.Play();
                    await Task.Delay(3000) //whatever length of audio is
                    iGravity = -3;
                }
                .
                .
                .

        }
    }
```

you can find more details in the docuementation-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Didn't work. I'v got a better result putting the "await Task.Delay(1000); after the if statment, but still not ideal. especially when you keep the "spacebar" pressed in.